# MyBatis intermitent error : org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Cannot get Configuration as configuration factory was not set

Tags: java, mybatis

We're using mybatis with mybatis spring from a long time and we hit an intermittent issue with one of our application :

```
org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Cannot get Configuration as configuration factory was not set.
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.loader.ResultLoaderMap$LoadPair.getConfiguration(ResultLoaderMap.java:220)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.loader.ResultLoaderMap$LoadPair.load(ResultLoaderMap.java:191)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.loader.AbstractEnhancedDeserializationProxy.invoke(AbstractEnhancedDeserializationProxy.java:78)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.loader.cglib.CglibProxyFactory$EnhancedDeserializationProxyImpl.intercept(CglibProxyFactory.java:184)
```

The strange thing is that my applicaton, a REST service, is used by a lot of consumer for a long time and only recently, without changing anything in the code base, this issue occurs. It occurs when my REST service is called from a spring-batch application that calls it thousands of times successively. Calling directly the same service works. The error comes intermittently (not always the same URL).

MyBatis is in version 3.2.8 and mybatis-spring 1.0. I tried with more recent versions (MyBatis 3.4.1 and mybatis-spring 1.2.3) but the same error occurs.

There should be a strange issues occuring because of specific race condition or something else ... is someone already have the same issue? It can't be a configuration issue as the application is working fine and only fails intermittently.

Regards,

Loïc

Answer (score 0):

Apparenlty, the issue is on the lazyloading functionality code where some race condition trigger the issue.
There appears to be a multi-thread related bug in the lazyfunctionality of MyBatis, so deactivating it works as a workaround.
I post a message on the mybatis user group because a real fix on MyBatis side is needed.

Waiting for the fix, if someone have the same issue as mine, the only way to workaround it is to deactivate the lazyloading functionality of mybatis :

```
<configuration>
   <settings>
      <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false" />
   </settings>
</configuration>
```

Regards,

Loïc